# Не парсится стиль Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, style

Следующий код выдаёт исключение Map style parsing failed при запуске:

```
   String styleText = "[" +
   "  {" +
   "    \"featureType\":\"poi.business\"," +
   "    \"elementType\":\"all\"," +
   "    \"stylers\":[" +
   "      {" +
   "        \"visibility\":\"off\"" +
   "      }" +
   "    ]" +
   "  }," +
   "  {" +
   "    \"featureType\":\"transit\"," +
   "    \"elementType\":\"all\"," +
   "    \"stylers\":[" +
   "      {" +
   "        \"visibility\":\"off\"" +
   "      }" +
   "    ]" +
   "  }" +
   "]";
  mMap = googleMap;

  MapStyleOptions style = new MapStyleOptions(styleText);

  mMap.setMapStyle(style);
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var styleText = [{
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      }
    ];

    var map;

    function initMap() {
      // Declare new style
      var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styleText, {
        name: "KAGG"
      });

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -34.397,
          lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
      });

      // Setup skin for the map
      map.mapTypes.set('KAGG_style', styledMap);
      map.setMapTypeId('KAGG_style');

    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNPpmrNOp_dyxwKRa7VFekvHt4ARNyWMk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Потому что это не String, а json. Посмотрите рабочий пример,  как добавить json стиля к карте, в сниппете.